# Understanding what I'm supposed to do

Tags: loops, methods, variable-assignment

This is an assignment for my Intro to Computer Science class:

A)  Write a class named Car that has the following fields
year: integer that represents the year
make:  String that represents the make
speed:  int holds the current speed

Constructors : a) no arg  : speed=0, make=”” , yearModel =2006
        b) :Accept year and make, set speed =0

Methods to get the values of yearModel, make and speed fields
accelerate method:  Add 1 to speed
brake method    subtract 1 from speed (speed can’t be less than 0)
set methods for year, make , speed
use javadoc comments and run javadoc to document the class

B)  Write an application that creates two cars.
Get car information from the user
Accelerate car#1 to 40mph (use loop) and then brake to 0
Accelerate car#2 to 30 mph (use loop) and then brake to 0.

I'm having trouble understand exactly what I'm supposed to do... Anyone have any idea what exactly the accelerate and brake methods are supposed to return? And how do I find the accelaration without knowing the rate at which the speed is incremented by 1?

Comment: to accelerate to 40, use a loop to increment speed from 0 to 40 in steps of 1.  He isn't interested in modeling the physics of acceleration, he just wants you to use a loop.  Accelerate and Brake don't need to return anything, but it might be useful for them to return the modified value of Speed.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. So the only statement inside each of the methods should be speed++; or speed--; ? And as for my main class, after prompting the user for inputs, what should be displayed afterward?

Comment: no idea - from what you posted it's not clear that anything should print.  This would be a good question for your professor or TA.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerate and brake methods are poorly named from a physics point of view: acceleration is related to velocity and time, but this simulation doesn't include a time dimension.  (Arguably, the time required to execute one loop iteration provides the time dimension, but with processors being as fast as they are, that is a somewhat poor way to include time in simulations these days.)

The methods should most likely return `void` and the speed should be incremented or decremented by one *each time the method is called.*

The simulation therefore doesn't support acceleration (or deceleration) "properly"; it's an oversimplified system intended for teaching basic techniques of object-oriented programming.

Comment: Not an expert here, but out of curiosity, why do you say accelerate and brake are poorly named in regards to physics? Are you implying brake should be something along the lines of decelerate?

Comment: @Bryan Good question; see edited answer.  I'm not saying that "brake" should be called "decelerate"; I'm suggesting that "decreaseSpeed" and "increaseSpeed" might be better names, because some (like the OP) might incorrectly assume that "accelerate" somehow uses the relationship `acceleration = changeInVelocity / time`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. So the only statement inside each of the methods should be speed++; or speed--; ? And as for my main class, after prompting the user for inputs, what should be displayed afterward?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you set a speed in your constructor - both methods should manipulate speed, one should increase it, second one should decrease it. Just think of it as regular car. You start driving, your speed is 0 but when you press the gas pedal, you increase the speed - break works other way around. Remember that when speed is 0, you can't make it smaller, also some cars have speed limit. Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. So the only statement inside each of the methods should be speed++; or speed--; ? And as for my main class, after prompting the user for inputs, what should be displayed afterward?

Comment: Well, that's for you to figure out :)